# InDesign - booklet printing multiple duplexed spreads on a single page

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I'm working on a booklet that is 3x5". I'd like to be able to print two two-page spreads per letter-size sheet of paper, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in InDesign.

Is this even possible? I'm mostly wanting to conserve paper.

Comment: Are you planning on printing this at home? I ask because if you have someone else print the book, then they should be the one setting up the book for print. I have a printer at work that can make basic booklets and I use imposition software to to set my files up for booklet printing.

Comment: Yes, I'm producing these on my own. What software do you use for imposition? I'm surprised InDesign doesn't handle this.

Comment: I will use InDesign to export to a PDF with bleed marks and then I use EFI Fiery Impose to setup the file for print, it's pretty expensive. There are several programs that can do this but I only have experience use EFI Fiery Impose.